# I can't access free space on my Ubuntu live USB?

Tags: partitioning, live-usb, iso, unallocated

I have 32 GB USB stick and wrote a Ubuntu ISO into it and now i could not get the space remaining in the stick. On booting from USB i am only getting 2 GB. Please help access the free unallocated space. I have tried creating a partition in USB with remaining space with disks utility, but it doesn't work.

Comment: With a Ubuntu ISO burnt to the stick using Rufus or similar tools your stick is seen as CD/DVD-drive by the system, so creating additional partitions is impossible. You can use [Easy2Boot](http://www.easy2boot.com/) to realize what you want to do. It is a Windows tool, but also there is a way to use it under Linux, check out their Website. The easy way of going is to use a smaller stick for your installer (they are not such expensive) and use the 32GB stick as a storage.

Answer (score 2):

If you create a persistent live USB boot drive with **mkusb**, you will use the whole drive.

The available space (after installing the operating system) will be shared between a linux ext partition with the label 'casper-rw' for persistence (storing what you install, save or tweak), and an NTFS partition with the label 'usbdata', that can be used to store data and to transfer data to and from computers running Windows.

See these links,

[help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb)

[help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/persistent](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/persistent)

[image]

Comment: no, it doesn't work. it creates an unallocated space with remaining space after installing. and I can't create a partition there.

Comment: What you describe will happen if you [use mkusb or another cloning tool to] create a **live-only** system in the USB drive. But if you use mkusb to create a **persistent live** drive, it will create five partitions, and it will use the whole drive. I think the only cases, when this will not work, is if the drive is read-only because it is failing, the so-called 'gridlock' condition, or if some process (for example a terminal window) will lock the pendrive, so that it cannot be unmounted. I will add a screenshot to illustrate how to make mkusb do what you want.